# How to process files in directory concurrently in .net

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm having issues processing files in parallel within a directory. I've read several similar questions and examples but I can't seem to find why my code causes exception.

My directory gets populated by other processes and will contain thousands of files at any one time. Each file has to be parsed and validated which takes time filesystem/network io etc. I need this step to be done in parallel, the rest has to be done serially.

Here's my code:

```
public void run()
{
    XmlMessageFactory factory = new XmlMessageFactory();
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(m_sourceDir);
    Dictionary<string, int> retryList = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    ConcurrentQueue<Tuple<XmlMsg,FileInfo>> MsgQueue = new
                                      ConcurrentQueue<Tuple<XmlMsg,FileInfo>>();

    //start worker to handle messages
    System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
        {
            XmlMsg msg;
            Tuple<XmlMsg, FileInfo> item;
            while (true)
            {
                if (!MsgQueue.TryDequeue(out item))
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    continue;
                }
                try
                {
                    msg = item.Item1;
                    /* processing on msg happens here */
                    handleMessageProcessed(item.Item2, ref retryList);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    //if this method is called it gives the 
                    //exception below
                    handleMessageFailed(item.Item2, e.ToString()); 
                }
            }
        }
    );

    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles(m_fileTypes);
            Partitioner<FileInfo> partitioner = Partitioner.Create(files, true);
            Parallel.ForEach(partitioner, f => 
            {
                try
                {
                    XmlMsg msg = factory.getMessage(messageType);
                    try
                    {
                        msg.loadFile(f.FullName);
                        MsgQueue.Enqueue(new Tuple<XmlMsg, FileInfo>(msg, f));
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        handleMessageFailed(f, e.ToString());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

static void handleMessageFailed(FileInfo f, string message)
{
    //Erorr here: 
    f.MoveTo(m_failedDir + f.Name);
    //"The process cannot access the file because it is 
    //being used by another process."}  System.Exception {System.IO.IOException}
}
```

**Using ConcurrentQueue how can it end up attempting to access a file twice at the same time?**

I have a test setup currently with 5000 files and this will happen at least once per run and on a different file each time. When I inspect the directory, the source file causing exception will have already been processed and is in the "processed" directory.

Comment: Current HDDs don't work good with parallel processing, so it can be a bottleneck if files are big. otherwise you can divide logic that loads file from file system, then pushes data for processing into new Queue, that will process them in parallel

Comment: I appreciate that, the HDD access isn't the bottleneck, the call to `loadFile()` pulls in files from the network etc so I want to do several of these at a time.

Comment: I think it's entirely likely that in some cases the process that is creating a file is still writing to it when one of the worker threads tries to do something with that file. Do you have any control over the file producers? If not, your best bet may be to let the thread sleep a short while and then retry - which isn't at all nice.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I'm currently testing with a set number of files in the directory before I run the application. Sometimes I also get "Unable to find the specified file" which suggests something is going wrong with the concurrency. Is my logic flawed?

Comment: So what if it is a network.  It is still one harddrive on the other end.  FileInfo[] files is one hard drive.  If you only need the file name then try the static Directory.EnumerateFiles()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a fair bit of head scratching the problem turned out to be annoyingly simple! What was happening was the parallel processing of the files in the directory was completing before the serial activity on the file, so the loop was restarting and re-adding some of the files to the Queue that were already in there.

For completeness here's the modified section of code:

```
while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles(m_fileTypes);
            Partitioner<FileInfo> partitioner = Partitioner.Create(files, true);
            Parallel.ForEach(partitioner, f => 
            {
                try
                {
                    XmlMsg msg = factory.getMessage(messageType);
                    try
                    {
                        msg.loadFile(f.FullName);
                        MsgQueue.Enqueue(new Tuple<XmlMsg, FileInfo>(msg, f));
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        handleMessageFailed(f, e.ToString());
                    }
                }
            });
            //Added check to wait for queue to deplete before 
            //re-scanning the directory
            while (MsgQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect a problem in `XmlMsg.loadFile()`

I think that you may have code like this in it:

```
public void loadFile(string filename)
{
    FileStream file = File.OpenRead(filename);

    // Do something with file

    file.Close();
}
```

If an exception occurs in the "do something with file" part, the file won't be closed because `file.Close()` will never be executed. Then you'll get the "file in use" exception inside `handleMessageFailed()`.

If so, the solution is to access the file in a `using` block as follows; then it will be closed even if an exception occurs:

```
public void loadFile(string filename)
{
    using (FileStream file = File.OpenRead(filename))
    {
        // Do something with file
    }
}
```

But assuming that this does turn out to be the problem, when you start using real files produced by external processes, you may have another issue if the external processes still have the files open when your worker threads try to process them.

Comment: There isn't anything like that in this code, but that's a good tip I'll take on board. Thanks!